# Ignore a property when deserializing using Json.Net with ItemRequired = Required.Always

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm using Json.Net to serialize and deserialize classes to json and back.

I added to a class marked with `[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]` (or `Required.Always`) a new get-only property. That results in the following `JsonSerializationException`:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Required property `'<PropertyName>'` not found in JSON

I thought marking that property with `JsonIgnore` would solve the issue, but that doesn't work.

How can I tell Json.Net that this property should be ignored?

Here's a minimal example reproducing the issue:

```
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
public class Hamster
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + LastName; }}
}

private static void Main()
{
    var hamster = new Hamster {FirstName = "Bar", LastName = "Arnon"};
    var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hamster);
    var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hamster>(serializeObject);
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Evidently `JsonIgnore` will only control the serialization in this case. `JsonIgnore` is required to specify that the `FullName` property should not be serialized to the json representation.

To ignore the property during deserialization we need to add the `JsonProperty` annotation with `Required = Required.Default` (which means not required).

So, this is how to avoid the `JsonSerializationException`:

```
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
public class Hamster
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + LastName; }}
}
```

Comment: why there is no JsonPropertyAttribute in Json.Net (.net core 5)?

Comment: @nAviD there is. Just checked. I assume you're not actually using Json.NET.