# Ignore missing fields in while Deserialisation using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have model created for deserialisation say,

```
class Object 
{
     public string prop1 {get; set}
     public string prop2 {get; set}
}
```

Now this will only work if my JSONstring contain both the fields i.e.

```
{
    "prop1" : "value prop1",
    "prop2" : "value prop2"
}
```

But this will fail if I have only one property in JSON i.e

```
{
    "prop1" : "value1"
}
```

how do i deserialise when there is a missing property and make it options.

Comment: ...so we still don't know what fails -- the code as provided does not fail. Except, of course, it doesn't even compile (missing semicolons after `set`). To be able to help, we need an example that a) compiles and b) fails.

Comment: *"but this will fail"*, it will not fail. With the example you provided here, it will deserialize without any problem. And when there is an error, it might be a good idea to share the error.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EIlnJk).  Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore a property when deserializing using Json.Net with ItemRequired = Required.Always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984416/ignore-a-property-when-deserializing-using-json-net-with-itemrequired-required)

Answer (score 0):

You can go for `Dynamic`

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{"prop1" : "value prop1","prop2" : "value prop2"}");
string p1 = stuff.prop1;
string p2 = stuff.prop2;
```

or `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`

```
dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse("{"prop1" : "value1"}");
string p1 = stuff.prop1;
```

Comment: Hi @Vinodh you can upvote the answer if it helped and if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This code works as is (apart from missing semicolons after sets).

If you want, on the other hand, to have an error in this case, use

`[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]`
 or `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)]`