# Json.net JsonIgnore doesn't work for nested classes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to serialize some third party json using Json.net and the problem is that they started sending Ids as strings insted of Guids. So I am trying to ignore the Ids within serialization but there seems to be a problem within nested properties that the JsonIgnore doesn't work. For that reason I decided to add my own Ids after but the serialisation itself doesn't seem to ignore what I need it to.

My classes used for serialization:

```
public class ItemA: General.Common
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public new Guid Id { get; set; } //hiding Guid Id Common
    public Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class Folder
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class ItemB: NotImportant
{
    //...
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; } = new List<Folder>();
    public List<ItemA> ItemAs{ get; set; } = new List<ItemA>();
}
```

My Code:

```
        var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        };

        string json = "some Json-that includes some Ids as strings";
        dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemB>(json, jsonSettings);
        //serialization error here that cannot convert string to Guid in ItemAs 
        ((ItemB)d).ItemAs.ForEach(x => x.Id = new Guid());
```

EDIT:
The error is something like this:

```
Error converting value "RgAAAAAD01CCe0GCRpDdKTQq2OCQBwAIuTruAfDrRZi9RPZnww3OAAAAAAEMAAAIuTruAfDrRZi9RPZnww3OAABE1hqaAAAA" to type 'System.Guid'...
```

Comment: `JsonIgnore` skips serialization, not deserialization.

Comment: Isn't everything in Json represented as string anyway, including GUID

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius yes but not every string can be deserialised into guid

Comment: I think this is a type conversion error, not serialization error.  change `new Guid()` to `new Guid().ToString()`

Comment: That's not a GUID, that's base64 data, if you want to be able to deserialize it change the `Id` type from `Guid` to `byte[]`

Comment: @Gusman I think the point is that OP wants to ignore the deserialization of this property altogether

Comment: @Gusman I know that is not a guid that's why I want to ignore that and put there my own guids

Comment: new Guid() makes an "empty" all-0 guid (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 ) where as Guid.NewGuid() makes an actual guid with a unique value

Comment: @Gusman that is valid only for field declarations

Comment: **Official Issue about this:** https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/463

Comment: I don't get it : why my solution which is working is not the accepted one ?

Comment: @Xavave I guess it's because this behaviour is intended by Json.Net. For sure your answer is good and correct. But still it is a workaround and not an answer to the actual question: **Why doesn't this work ?** (still voted your answer up)

Comment: @FelixD.thank you :) never the less, the exact question is not clear, Dracke doesn't precisely asks "Why doesn't this work ?" or if he wants a workaround, does he ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is an official Issue about this:**

[Issue #463 - JsonIgnore attribute on shadowed properties](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/463)

*They are separate properties, one happens to be hiding the other. By ignoring the one on Derived then the property on base is no longer hidden and is being serialized instead. If you want to ignore both then place [JsonIgnore] on both, or if you want [JsonIgnore] on the Derived class to ignore both then base the property virtual and override it on Derived.* - **[JamesNK](https://github.com/JamesNK)**

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to ignore during deserialize : fully working example based on your code: (see [Ignore a property when deserializing using Json.Net with ItemRequired = Required.Always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984416/ignore-a-property-when-deserializing-using-json-net-with-itemrequired-required))

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
public class ItemA : General.Common
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
    public new Guid Id { get; set; } //hiding Guid Id Common
    public Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class Folder
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class ItemB : NotImportant
{
    //...
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; } = new List<Folder>();
    public List<ItemA> ItemAs { get; set; } = new List<ItemA>();
}
public class Test
{



    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    };
   //ItemB b = new ItemB()
    //{
    //    Folders = new List<Folder>() {
    //        new Folder() { Id = "1", Path = "myPath1" },
    //        new Folder() { Id = "2", Path = "myPath2" },
    //        new Folder() { Id = "3", Path = "myPath3" } },
    //    ItemAs = new List<ItemA>() {
    //        new ItemA() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ParentFolder = new Folder()
    //        { Id = "p1", Path = "parentpath1" } },
    //new ItemA()
    //{ Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    //    ParentFolder = new Folder()
    //{ Id = "p2", Path = "parentpath2" } }}
    //};
    //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b);
    string json = "{\"Folders\":[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Path\":\"myPath1\"},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"Path\":\"myPath2\"},{\"Id\":\"3\",\"Path\":\"myPath3\"}],\"ItemAs\":[{\"Id\":\"RgAAAAAD01CCe0GCRpDdKTQq2OCQBwAIuTruAfDrRZi9RPZnww3OAAAAAAEMAAAIuTruAfDrRZi9RPZnww3OAABE1hqaAAAA\",\"ParentFolder\":{\"Id\":\"p1\",\"Path\":\"parentpath1\"}},{\"Id\":\"c0af33a9-3e6f-4405-a2d4-ff469cb67fce\",\"ParentFolder\":{\"Id\":\"p2\",\"Path\":\"parentpath2\"}}]}";
    dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemB>(json, jsonSettings);
    //no serialization error 
    ((ItemB)d).ItemAs.ForEach(x => x.Id = Guid.NewGuid());

}
```

[image: results screenshot]

Comment: what is `b` for in your example ?

Comment: b was used to generate a json string , that I changed then to insert the faulty guid "RgAAAAAD01CCe0GCRpDdKTQq2OCQBwAIuTruAfDrRZi9RPZnww3OAAAAAAEMAAAIuTruAfDrRZi9RPZnww3OAABE1hqaAAAA".I've updated my code to comment it