# How to merge multiple lists based on a condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes as follows:

```
public class SensorReading
{
    public DateTime DatetimeStamp { get; set; }
    public float Sound { get; set; }
    public float Temperature { get; set; }
    public float Humidity { get; set; }

    public SensorReading()
    {
    }
}

public class API_Obj
{
    public DateTime DateTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }

    public API_Obj()
    {
    }
}
```

And I'm getting my sensor readings from a REST API; however, it separates the **Sound**, **Temperature** and **Humidity** readings into different API Endpoints. Hence I've made 3 separate API calls and stored each reading type into a list of Type List<API_Obj>. The code looks something this:

```
//set static objects
List<API_Obj> SoundReadings = GetReadings("sound");
List<API_Obj> TempReadings = GetReadings("temperature");
List<API_Obj> HumidReadings = GetReadings("humidity");
```

Now I would like to merge the 3 lists **according to the DateTimeStamp** class property. I've come up with this so far:

```
var AllReadings = SoundReadings.Union(TempReadings).Union(HumidReadings).GroupBy(obj => obj.DateTimeStamp)
    .Select(newObj => new SensorReading()
    {
        DateTimeStamp = newObj.Key,
        // Sound = ???
        // Temperature = ???
        // Humidity = ???
    }).ToList();
```

This would return 0 for Sound, Temperature and Humidity, however. How do I continue from here?

Comment: Does something about API_Obj indicate its type?

Comment: @Llama Nope. Each reading type uses the same API_Obj class. This is what I find problematic because I don't know how to determine if API_Obj.Value represents Sound, Temperature or Humidity...

Comment: @NathanGurdoski Why not add a property to your `API_Obj` class which will signify it's type: Sound, Temperature, Humidity. You can then decorare it as `JSONIgnore`, so it isn't bothered with when deserializing, then before your LINQ query you can do a `List.ForEach` and set the type of each object in the list so each object can be identified as Sound, Temperature or Humidity.

Comment: Geesh. If the number of datasets is small, just use temporaries.

Comment: `SoundReadings.Select(obj => (type: "sound", obj.stamp, obj.value)). Concat( TempReadings.Select(obj => (type: "temp", obj.stamp, obj.value)). (...)` and you've got it without modifying the datasource or without tinkering with patching up the jsons..

Comment: You can also easily create 3 classes: SoundObj derived from API_Obj, TempObj, HumObj alike, and deserialize the Jsons not as List<API_Obj> but as List<SoundObj> and then .Concat them as IEnumerable<API_Obj> and then use the simplest type checking/filtering in form of OfType/is/as/etc in detailed ops later

Comment: @NathanGurdoski: Please ask a *new* question if you have another issue. Don't update the already answered question.

Comment: Try something like this:

`...GroupBy(obj => TrimSeconds(obj.DateTimeStamp))`

TrimSeconds method:

`DateTime TrimSeconds(DateTime dt) => new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, 0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep track of the type of value one way or another. Given your current type definitions, something like this should work:

```
var AllReadings = SoundReadings.Select(x => new { x.DatetimeStamp, x.Value, Type = "SoundReadings" })
    .Union(TempReadings.Select(x => new { x.DatetimeStamp, x.Value, Type = "TempReadings" })
    .Union(HumidReadings.Select(x => new { x.DatetimeStamp, x.Value, Type = "HumidReadings" })))
    .GroupBy(obj => obj.DatetimeStamp)
    .Select(newObj => new SensorReading()
    {
        DatetimeStamp = newObj.Key,
        Sound = newObj.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "SoundReadings")?.Value,
        Temperature = newObj.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "TempReadings")?.Value,
        Humidity = newObj.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "HumidReadings")?.Value
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: For such simple task, created a bunch of intermediate objects and allocations. Performance is a luxury.

Comment: Sure, if there are a lots of objects to process and performance is a thing, there are certainly better ways.

Answer (score 1):

What you came up with is nice, and of course you've got the `newObj.Key` there, but you didn't notice what `newObj` is: it is **the group** itself. A group = a collections of items from under that common key.

That's why the 'grouping' `newObj` implements not only the Key property, but also `IEnumerable<API_Obj>` interface, so you can inspect the items that fell to that group.

That is, if you've originally had:

```
SoundReadings:
    - date:0011, value: aa
    - date:0022, value: bb
    - date:0033, value: cc
TempReadings:
    - date:0011, value: dd
    - date:0055, value: ee
HumidReadings:
    - date:0055, value: ff
    - date:0066, value: gg
```

You will end up with these groups:

```
11:
    - date:0011, value: aa (sound)
    - date:0011, value: dd (temp)
22:
    - date:0022, value: bb (sound)
33:
    - date:0033, value: cc (sound)
44:
    - date:0055, value: ee (temp)
    - date:0055, value: ff (humid)
66:
    - date:0066, value: gg (humid)
```

Now, in your .Select() at the end, you have to inspect not only the Key with the date, but also the whole set of items held in `newObj` and find an item for Sound, and use its value for Sound, find an item for Temp and use its value for Temp, and so on.

For example, just to give you a general idea:

```
.Select(newObj => new SensorReading()
{
    DateTimeStamp = newObj.Key,
    Sound = newObj.Where(.....).FirstOrDefault()?.Value,
    ...
}).ToList();
```

Mind three things though:

- grouping doesn't guarantee that the item will be there. If there are some holes in the data set, you may find groups that don't have any Sound at all. Or you may find groups that have multiple Sounds for given date. All depends on the input data
- grouping won't remember for you that a Sound is a Sound. If all your API_Obj are identical and only contain different dates and different Values, you have to have a way to determine where did that value come from in the first place. Note how I added "(sound)" to the list above. You may need something like this in your data model as well, or else you may be not able to differentiate a value from Sound source from a value from Temp source.
- keying/grouping by date is tricky. Be extra careful here, because Time likes to change. If it's not only dates, but whole timestamps, with seconds, milliseconds, and so on, you may suddenly notice that all groups have only 1 element, because there were no timestamps from Sounds that perfecly matched timestamps from Temps. They might have been similar even up to seconds, but if milliseconds were different, then the keys were different. You get the idea already probably.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you could modify your `API_Obj` class to hold a new string property called `APIType` and you can decorate the property with `JsonIgnore` attribute.

```
public class API_Obj
{
    public DateTime DatetimeStamp { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string APIType { get; set; }

    public API_Obj()
    {
    }
}
```

Then after you do your API Calls, use the `List.ForEach` to set the new property on each object of the list:

```
List<API_Obj> SoundReadings = GetReadings("sound");
List<API_Obj> TempReadings = GetReadings("temperature");
List<API_Obj> HumidReadings = GetReadings("humidity");

//set the APIType property on each list object
SoundReadings.ForEach(z => z.APIType = "sound");
TempReadings.ForEach(z => z.APIType = "temperature");
HumidReadings.ForEach(z => z.APIType = "humidity");
```

Now you can use these to determine which property to set in your Linq Query

Comment: Yup. That would work. I like the typed deserialization, because often the data models tend to start to differ in future and it really helps in preventing mixing up data of different kinds, but of course tagged objects you proposed would work as well.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks for the feedback. Your proposed solution is good as well.

Comment: I've combined your answer with @mm8's and also added the `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]` annotation as suggested from another thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984416/ignore-a-property-when-deserializing-using-json-net-with-itemrequired-required)

Comment: @NathanGurdoski Cool. Glad you got a solution that works for you. Although from what I read on Microsoft's documentation, `JsonIgnore` should be honored on serialization and deserialization: [system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not performant for such task, I would suggest the following function:

```cs
public static void MergeList<TItem, TKey, TResult>(IEnumerable<TItem> items, Dictionary<TKey, TResult> result,
    Func<TItem, TKey> keyFunc, Action<TItem, TResult> setterAction)
    where TResult : new()
{
    if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));
    if (keyFunc == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keyFunc));
    if (setterAction == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(setterAction));
    if (result == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(result));

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var key = keyFunc(item);
        if (!result.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
        {
            value = new TResult();
            result.Add(key, value);
        }

        setterAction(item, value);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
var result = new Dictionary<DateTime, SensorReading>();
MergeList(SoundReadings, result, x => x.DatetimeStamp, (a, r) => r.Sound = a.Value);
MergeList(TempReadings,  result, x => x.DatetimeStamp, (a, r) => r.Temperature = a.Value);
MergeList(HumidReadings, result, x => x.DatetimeStamp, (a, r) => r.Humidity = a.Value);
```